# How do I make a function that calculates the correct offset based on a pagesize and a page number in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, pagination, plpgsql

I'm trying to make a function in PostgreSQL that takes a pageSize and a page Number as params and from that, calculates the offset. This makes paging a lot easier for me.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_paging(page_size INT, page_number INT)
    RETURNS INT AS $calculate_paging$
DECLARE
offset INT;
max_int INT = 2147483647;
BEGIN
    offset = CASE WHEN CAST(page_size AS BIGINT) * (page_number - 1) > max_int 
                THEN max_int 
                ELSE page_size * (page_number - 1)
    RETURN offset
END;
$calculate_paging$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This does not work, I keep getting synthax errors. But the idea is to calculate the offset and return the offset value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without considering the real purpose of the function and just focusing on the syntax errrors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_paging(page_size INT, page_number INT)
RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE max_int INT = 2147483647;
BEGIN
    IF page_size::bigint * (page_number - 1) > max_int THEN 
      RETURN max_int;
    ELSE 
      RETURN page_size * (page_number - 1);
    END IF;    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```